# Using a template function in an anonymous namespace

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to use [Strong Types](https://www.fluentcpp.com/posts/#strong-types) and to add stream operator for them.

In my source file I put all of these helpers in an anonymous namespace. One of these helpers is using a template stream operator (`utils::to_hex(T)`) defined in another header.

```
namespace { // Anonymous namespace

// Example custom strong type
using custom_type = utils::StrongType<std::uint32_t, struct Custom>;

// Stream operator for custom type
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &_os, const custom_type &_value)
{
    return (_os << utils::to_hex(static_cast<std::uint32_t>(_value)));
}

}

int main(void)
{
    custom_type c = 0xDEADBEEF;

    std::cout << c << std::endl;
}
```

The whole code: http://cpp.sh/2ln7q

I cannot compile this code. I am stuck with:

```
test.cc: In function ‘std::ostream& {anonymous}::operator<<(std::ostream&, const custom_type&)’:
test.cc:72:14: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ and ‘utils::ToHex<unsigned int>’)
  return (_os << utils::to_hex(static_cast<std::uint32_t>(_value)));
```

Using the [cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh/2ln7q) compiler I got:

```
 In function 'std::ostream& {anonymous}::operator<<(std::ostream&, const custom_type&)':
73:65: error: cannot bind 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream<char>&&'
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/istream:39:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/sstream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/iomanip:45,
                 from 3:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/ostream:602:5: note: initializing argument 1 of 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, const _Tp&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Tp = utils::ToHex<unsigned int>]'
     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&& __os, const _Tp& __x)
```

When I remove the anonymous namespace of if I use the `static` keyword everything is fine.

Comment: It seems there's an overload of `operator<<` for `utils::ToHex` that, for reasons unclear, takes its `basic_ostream` argument by rvalue reference (which makes no sense). If you are the author of this overload, fix it to take a "normal" lvalue reference. If you don't control that code, you may be able to work around by writing `std::move(_os) << utils::to_hex(...)`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Those are one of the standard overloads.

Comment: @0x499602D2 I'm not sure what you mean by "standard" here. `utils::ToHex` or `utils::to_hex` are not part of the C++ standard library, to the best of my knowledge. Which standard do you believe prescribes them?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Aren't you referring to `operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&& __os, const _Tp& __x)`? This is one of the overloads that come with `ostream`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik The overload operator for `utils::ToHex` is define in the code (see http://cpp.sh/2ln7q line 50). But it seems that it is not taken into account. When I put this operator in the anonymous namespace it is ok ...

Comment: @0x499602D2 Ah, I see. So basically, there's no suitable overload of `operator<<` for `utils::ToHex`, and the compiler is picking [a generic one](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) (which doesn't work anyway).

Comment: I was able to get it down to this [basic example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aaf966d0666e00d2). For whatever reason normal lookup rules cannot find your version of `operator<<` while being called from within a `operator<<` overload. The workaround was to make an explicit call to the operator while looking at the outer namespace.

Comment: Define that operator in `utils` namespace, together with the class it's acting on, so it can be found by the argument-dependent lookup. At the moment, it's simply not found by name lookup.

Comment: @0x499602D2 It's simple. `operator<<(std::ostream &_os, const custom_type &_value)` hides the name `operator<<` in enclosing namespace, so ordinary lookup cannot find it. This is common. The trick is to always define free-standing helper functions in the same namespace as their arguments, to be found by ADL. That's pretty much the reason ADL exists.

Comment: @0x499602D2 It works. Thanks ! Can you post your response please ?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Your solution to put the operator in the `utils` namespace is also working. Please post your answer.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yes but how do unnanamed namespaces tie into this? If you just get rid of the anon namespace it works even if `operator<<` is "hiding" the name in the enclosing scope.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Without the extra namespace, the two overloads are in the same namespace (the global one), and participate in overload resolution equally. Neither is hiding the other. There's no longer an "enclosing scope" - the two names are in the same scope.

Comment: Unqualified name lookup runs `until it finds at least one declaration of any kind, at which time the lookup stops and no further scopes are examined`. So namespace scope + ADL scope. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup